# Wrap first character in HTML tag using jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: html, replace, tags, character

I'd like to insert (wrap) a first character of a certain DIV into a `<span>` tag.

Example:

```
<div class="myclass">A few words...</div>
```

to

```
<div class="myclass"><span>A</span> few words...</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please, when asking questions try always to provide a [mcve] , snippet code of your best try (like you did with your previous two questions).

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a way to **style** your first character,  **use CSS** [**::first-letter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

```css
.myclass::first-letter {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">A few <b>words</b>...</div>
```

If you really want JavaScript / **jQuery** to insert a wrapping `<span>` element than:

```js
$(".myclass").html((i, h) => `<span>${h.slice(0,1)}</span>${h.slice(1)}`);
```

```css
.myclass span {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">A few <b>words</b>...</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or in **JavaScript**:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".myclass").forEach(el => {
  const h = el.innerHTML;
  el.innerHTML = `<span>${h.slice(0,1)}</span>${h.slice(1)}`;
});
```

```css
.myclass span {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">A few <b>words</b>...</div>
```

- As you can notice in all three examples the inner HTML (i.e: `<b>words</b>...`) is preserved.
- In the above JavaScript and jQuery examples we still miss a check that the actual first character of the innerHTML is not actually a *Tag begin* `<`, so make sure you don't have i.e: `<i>A few <b>words</b>...</i>` or it will fail. In that case the code above should be expanded.
- By using the JS solutions, on a large document scale, you might experience flickers caused by re-layouting and repaints.
- I'd still suggest to try to use the **CSS approach**. It's faster for the browser and provides a better UX.
- [String.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: I need a span tag to add a linebreak after, using a ::after pseudo-class. Unfortunately, the HTML code is dynamically generated, so spaces, linebreaks and tabs are inserted as the first character, invalidating the code.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a method I tested out and worked. I put an example event listener of a click event.

```js
$('.myclass').click(function() {
   let myText = $('.myclass').text ();
   let myChar = myText.substring(0,1);
   let myNewText = `<span>${myChar}</span>${myText.substring(1,myText.length)}`;
   $('.myclass').html(myNewText);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const div = $('.myclass');

div.append('<span>A</span> few words...');

console.log(div.html());

//use jQuery#append.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It isn't a solution to the problem.